# Network displays 802.11g instead of n, and I can't log in with the correct key

Tags: wireless-networking, networking, adapter, 802.11n, 802.11g

I just bought a Linksys Wireless-N PCI Adapter with Dual-Band, and I tried to log into the usual 2.4GHz 802.11n network with the usual pass key. Only now, the list says it's a 802.11g network and my pass key is incorrect.

Does anyone know this problem? And/Or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure WPA2 (AES-CCMP) is enabled on your 802.11n network. The 802.11n spec requires devices to decline connecting at N rates with WEP or TKIP (original WPA), because most implementations of those ciphers can't keep up with N rates.  Not all N clients honor this requirement, but newer ones usually do, because the Wi-Fi Alliance's final N certification testing requires devices to honor it.